# How to query in EF core with OrderByDescending, Take, Select and FirstOrDefault

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework

So I've got a table named Summaries, it looks like this [image]

I need to get to sum the latest entries of TotalPieces based on CoveredDate and should be grouped by ServiceCode and queried by month
for example, ServiceCode 'A' has entries on 2020-01-01, 2020-01-02, 2020-01-03, 2020-01-31, 2020-02-01, 2020-02-28, 2020-02-29 
and ServiceCode 'B' has entries on 2020-01-01, 2020-01-02, 2020-01-31, 2020-02-20, 2020-02-21,
i need to get the sum based on month, lastest entry on 'A' on January is on 2020-01-31,  and 'B' has latest entry on 2020-01-31, I need to sum their 'TotalPieces', so I should get 25 + 25 = 50.

basically i need to do is

- Get all the lastest entries based on `CoveredDate` and month/year
- Sum the `TotalPieces` by `ServiceCode`

i got a working query, but this is just a workaround because i can't get it right on query.

```
            int sum_totalpieces = 0;
            foreach (var serviceCode in service_codes)
            {
                var totalpieces = _DbContext.ActiveSummaries.Where(acs =>
                                    acs.CoveredDate.Date.Month == query_month
                                    && acs.CoveredDate.Date.Year == query_year
                                    && acs.service_codes == serviceCode
                                    )
                    .OrderByDescending(obd => obd.CoveredDate)
                    .Take(1)
                    .Select(s => s.TotalPieces)
                    .ToList()
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                sum_totalpieces += totalpieces;
            }
```

the `service_codes` is just a List of string

If you guys could just get rid of the `foreach` block their and make it `services_codes.Contains()` on query, or another workaround to make the result faster that would be great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any chance you could break that 200 word sentence describing the algorithm up into bullet points so it's easier to understand? Is it true to say you want to "sum the totalpieces of only the latest (according to covered date) row in each service code?"

Comment: No, wait.. it's "sum the totalpieces of only the latest (according to covered date) row in each (service code, month)"?

Comment: The loop can be replaced with a GroupBy. If the query is “slow”, the underlying table layout and resulting query plan might need to be examined.

Comment: my where clause just describes the month, year, and service codes. because i need to query it by month

Comment: @user2864740 thats what im trying to do, but i cant figure it out

Comment: Where(month_is).GroupBy(service_code).Select(first_in_group).DefaultIfEmpty().Sum()

Comment: @user2864740 please don't post answers in comments - flesh it out into a full answer, as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it, but I don't think it will translate to SQL and run at the server:

```
    _DbContext.ActiveSummaries
            .Where(b =>
                b.CoveredDate >= new DateTime(2020,1,1) &&
                b.CoveredDate < new DateTime(2020,2,1) && 
                new [] { "A", "B" }.Contains(b.ServiceCode)
            )
            .GroupBy(g => g.ServiceCode)
            .Sum(g => g.OrderByDescending(gb=> gb.CoveredDate).First().TotalPieces);
```

If you want to do it as a raw SQL for best performance it would look like:

```
SELECT SUM(totalpieces)
FROM 
  x 
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT servicecode, MAX(covereddate) cd 
    FROM x 
    WHERE x.servicecode IN ('A','B') AND covereddate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'
  )y ON x.servicecode=y.servicecode and x.covereddate = y.cd
```

Comment: tried it, but throws me this error, Processing of the LINQ expression 'AsQueryable<ActiveSummaries>(OrderByDescending<ActiveSummaries, DateTime>(
    source: NavigationTreeExpression
        Value: default(IGrouping<string, ActiveSummaries>)
        Expression: (Unhandled parameter: e), 
    keySelector: (gb) => gb.CoveredDate))' by 
'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed.
 This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.

Comment: Try putting a `.ToList()` after the Where()/before the groupby. I expect that it cannot be translated to sql; tolisting it will download the rows and the rest of the operation will proceed locally